# html css positioning divs below other elements without adjusting html

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have four menu items (h3) and four lists relating to the menu items.
i want to align the list elements exactly below the single menu items. its possible that another menu & list item should be displayed dynamically. so its possible that three or four items shown up.

at this time, when the fourth item is displayed, the layout crashes. of course...because the list-divs have fixed position.

i can't really adjust the html otherwise it screw up my app-layout (it's the jquery ui accordion in app - view)

so my question: 
is it possible to dynamically show and hide the elements from the page and they will always have the relatively right space between each other?

maybe using flexbox?

thank you and much love.

i have the following code:

```css
 #navigation {
      width:100%;
    }

    /*Menü-Items (Behälter, Sperrmüll, Veranlagungen, Service)*/     
    #navigation h3 {
          font-size: 1.3rem;
          float:left;
          height: 22%;
          width: 14%;
          margin-left: 10%;         
          background-color: #edf3d0;
          border-top-right-radius: 15px;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
          border-left: solid 8px transparent;
          border-right: solid 8px transparent;
          margin-top: 3rem;
        }


        #navigation > h3:nth-child(1) {
            margin-top: 3rem;
        }

        #navigation h3 {
            border-left: solid 8px #a4c412;
            border-right: solid 8px #a4c412;
        }

        /*** Liste unter Menüpunkt Behälter****/
        #navigation > div.dropdown.behaelter_content {
            left: 10%;
        }
        /*** Liste unter Menüpunkt Sperrmüll****/
        #navigation > div.dropdown.sperrmuell_content {
           left: 35%
        }
        /*** Liste unter Menüpunkt Mein Bereich****/
        #navigation > div.dropdown.mein_bereich_content {
           left:60%;
        }

        /****ausgeblendet: Veranlagungen***/
        #navigation > div.dropdown.veranlagungen_content {
          left:85%
        }

    .dropdown {
        width: 15% !important;
        position:fixed;
        top: 60%;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="navigation" class="center">

        <h3 id="behaelter" class="behaelter_content ">
            <img class="icon" src="bibliotheken/images/dustbin.svg" />

            <span class="text">Beh&auml;lter</span>

        </h3>

        <div class="dropdown behaelter_content ">

            <ul class="rectangle-list">
                <!--li><a id="behaelterliste">Liste der Beh&auml;lter</a></li>-->
                <li class="behaelter_content "><a id="behaelter_verwalten">Beh&auml;lter verwalten</a></li>
                <li class="behaelter_content "><a id="schaden">Schadensmeldungen</a></li>
                <!--li><a id="personendaten">Personen- <br />und Beh&auml;lterdaten</a></!--li>-->
                <li class="behaelter_content "><a id="leerungsdaten">Leerungsdaten</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <h3 id="sperrmuell" class="sperrmuell_content">
            <img id="sperrmuell" class="icon" src="bibliotheken/images/recycling-truck.svg" />

            <span class="text">
                Sperrm&uuml;ll
            </span>
        </h3>
        <div class="dropdown sperrmuell_content">
            <ul class="rectangle-list">
                <li><a id="sp_anmelden1">Sperrm&uuml;ll anmelden</a></li>
                <li><a id="sp_termine">&Uuml;bersicht der Termine</a></li>
                <li><a id="sp_termine_aendern">Termin &auml;ndern</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>



        <h3 id="veranlagungen" class="veranlagungen_content">
            <img class="icon" src="bibliotheken/images/money.svg" />

            <span class="text">
                Veranlagungen
            </span>
        </h3>
        <div class="dropdown veranlagungen_content">
            <ul class="rectangle-list">
                <li><a id="uebersicht_veranlagungen">&Uuml;bersicht der<br /> Veranlagungen</a></li>
                <li><a id="uebersicht_zahlungen">&Uuml;bersicht der<br>Zahlungen</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <h3 id="mein_bereich" class="mein_bereich_content">
            <img class="icon" src="bibliotheken/images/information.svg" />

            <span class="text">
                Mein Bereich
            </span>
        </h3>
        <div class="dropdown mein_bereich_content">
            <ul class="rectangle-list">
                <li><a id="stammdaten">Meine pers&ouml;nlichen Daten</a></li>
                <!--li><a id="eigenkomp">Eigenkompostierung</a></!--li>-->
                <li><a id="objekte">Meine Objekte</a></li>
                <li><a id="bankdaten">Meine Bankdaten</a></li>
                <li><a id="kontakt">Kontakt und Reklamationen</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've kind of answered your own question by saying can I use Flexbox. You can add `display:flex` to your container `#navigation`. I've put this in a codepen and it seems to works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrOaVJ. Have a look and let me know what you think.

To expand on this answer on your `#navigation` if you add the following:

```
#navigation {
  display:flex; //define flex container
  flex-wrap:nowrap; //this will prevent the items from wrapping to the next line
}
```

Here is some further reading and an excellent guide to Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: lol, i tried it a thousand times with display:flex; and it totally screws everything up. now it's fine. thank you! but how can i "auto-adjust" the list-items, to get close to each other when there are (for example) only two menuitems? can i work around the fixed left-values of the lists?

Comment: @Fehler40 when you say auto-adjust do you mean having them grow and shrink to fit inside their container? If so, you can use the `flex-grow` property on the child elements. Take a look at the link in the answer for some further information.

Answer (score 0):

found a nice solution with jQuerys **position()**

```
var lefts = $("#navigation > h3.sperrmuell_content").position().left;
$("#navigation > div.dropdown.sperrmuell_content").css("left", lefts);
```

and

```
 #navigation > div
    {
        margin-left:100px;
    }
```

so the space between the lists are always the same like from the menuitems above :)